# How to create dynamic attribute aliases in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, metaprogramming, alias

In class definition I got a list of attributes that I want to return other than database's values unless the container for store of those values is nil:

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base

   CONFIRM_DATA = ["attr1", "attr2"]
   # "attr1", "attr2" is database fields

   CONFIRM_DATA.each do |att|
      alias_attribute "original_#{att}".to_sym, att.to_sym
      define_method att.to_sym do
         temp_attr_store[ att.to_sym ] || read_attribute( "original_#{att}".to_sym)
      end
   end
end
```

So as you see, I try to store in `temp_attr_store` some temp values for the attributes: they should appear instead of db values and hopefully affect the associations for the object.

The code above does not work, all `attr1` access results in nil.
Thank you!

Comment: What is `temp_attr_store`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it is a just an attribute in the same class. A hash. It is assigned from outside of the class.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so effectively, I want give an ability of the user of the class's instance to assign like this: label.temp_attr_store["attr1"] = 3 and after that label.attr1 should return "3". And all associations dependent on this attr1 (if it is a foreign key) to change also. But I need model to know nothing about it so when user call save it saves no changes