# Rails 4 - Generic alias_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, metaprogramming, alias

I'm trying to make generic alias_attribute to some models attributes.

Since I need to keep on databases the original names of the fields I wish to make the attributes the more readable possible.

For example: `GenericDataBaseColumn #=> generic_data_base_column`

So far this is what I've got but isn't working as intended:

```
self.attribute_names.
    each { |attr| alias_attribute attr.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).
                   join("_").downcase.to_sym, :attr }
```

I'm using the `alias_attribute` because I'm using some of the fields I'm receiving them as JSON and serializing them, so I wanna keep the possibility to change them in the future by only making a migration.

I'm asking this since I've researched and the only similar question is which isn't answered still.

> [How to create dynamic attribute aliases in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092815)

I'm still not sure if this is possible to achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently looks like was a misunderstanding of how should I invoke the attributes.
Instead of `self.attribute_names` should be `attribute_names` since the method should be called only for instantiated elements.

Also, after this first fix, I had to skip all the attributes with the same name, because this will cause `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)`

The final implementation should be like this:

```
# Defining alias attributes
attribute_names.each do |attr|
  next if attr.blank? || (attr == attr.underscore)
  alias_attribute attr.underscore.to_sym, attr.to_sym
end
```

Hope this helps someone else.
Also if a some have answer feel free to post it. Thanks

Comment: Nice solution. I have added it to my app - which is using a legacy database with CamelCase names. I have a subclass of ApplicationRecord which I added this code in after_initialize. Because I'm doing this in the context of a record (not a model), I used self.class.alias_attribute instead of alias_attribute